# Wrap stack li elements inside div

Tags: html, css

I have html like this:

```
<ul class="edit-list">
      <li>
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <div class="frame"> 
            <img>
        </div>
      </li>
     <li>
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <div class="frame">
            <img>
        </div>
      </li>
     <li>
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <div class="frame">
            <img>
        </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Which I've already manage to look like this:

[image]

My desired appearance would be like this:

[image]

So the first element is 2 times bigger than the other and the rest should stack one upon another and in second row normally next to each other.

Comment: Where is your existing CSS? This looks like simple floats should deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly possible using `float`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
.frame {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 10px;
}
.large {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="edit-list">
  <li>
    <div class="frame large">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="frame">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="frame">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="frame">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="frame">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="frame">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: for visual rhythm I have slightly increased the size of the 'large' div.